# JTable not selectable in Windows Pro Builder

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i was working on a Java Project, but i found a problem when i was going to use the JTable in the Design section in Eclipse by using the Windows Pro Builder plug-in.

I tried selecting the JTable in the "Components" section of WindowsProBuilder but after clicking on it, it doesn't get selected, just like an empty button, unlike all the other components. I also tried inserting the JTable via line of code.